# Array empty when it should clearly contain elements

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2, fatal-error

I keep getting a `fatal error: Index out of range` error. My array should clearly contain elements from the images below but it is empty. Been Trying to debug it for hours, I am not too sure what's causing. Please see the images and code below.

```
        var topTest = [t2, t4, t8, t7, t2, t5, t8, t6 ]
    for (index, point) in topTest.enumerate() {

        spritesPath.append(point)

        if index < topTest.count - 1    {

        var previousArrayIndex = (index - 1)%topTest.count
        if previousArrayIndex == -1 {
            previousArrayIndex += topTest.count
        }
        var nextArrayIndex = (index + 1)%topTest.count

        var firstIndex = topPositions.indexOf(point)
        var secondIndex = topPositions.indexOf(topTest[nextArrayIndex])
        var firstArray = top[firstIndex!]
        var secondArray = top[secondIndex!]
        var middleIndex1 = 0
        var middleArray1 = [CGPoint]()
        var middleRandomArrayLength1 : UInt32 = 0
        var middleRandomPointIndex1 = 0
        var middleIndex2 = 0
        var middleArray2 = [CGPoint]()
        var middleRandomArrayLength2 : UInt32 = 0
        var middleRandomPointIndex2 = 0

        if point.x > topTest[nextArrayIndex].x {

            if point.x > topTest[previousArrayIndex].x   {

                let rightPositionsX = rightPositions.map({ $0.x })
                middleArray1 = firstArray.filter({rightPositionsX.contains($0.x)})

                middleRandomArrayLength1 =  UInt32(middleArray1.count)
                middleRandomPointIndex1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(middleRandomArrayLength1))
                spritesPath.append(middleArray1[middleRandomPointIndex1])

                middleIndex1 = rightPositions.indexOf(middleArray1[middleRandomPointIndex1])!
                middleArray1 = right[middleIndex1]
                let middleArray1X = middleArray1.map({ $0.x })
                var midArray2 = secondArray.filter({middleArray1X.contains($0.x)})
                midArray2 = midArray2.filter({element in point.x > element.x && topTest[nextArrayIndex].x < element.x })

                middleRandomArrayLength2 =  UInt32(midArray2.count)
                middleRandomPointIndex2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(middleRandomArrayLength2))
                spritesPath.append(middleArray2[middleRandomPointIndex2])
            }
            else{
                let secondArrayX = secondArray.map({ $0.x })
                middleArray1 = firstArray.filter({secondArrayX.contains($0.x)})

                middleArray1 = middleArray1.filter({element in point.x > element.x && topTest[nextArrayIndex].x < element.x })
                middleRandomArrayLength1 =  UInt32(middleArray1.count)
                middleRandomPointIndex1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(middleRandomArrayLength1))
                spritesPath.append(middleArray1[middleRandomPointIndex1])

            }
        }

else
        {

            if point.x < topTest[previousArrayIndex].x   {
                let leftPositionsX = leftPositions.map({ $0.x })
                middleArray1 = firstArray.filter({leftPositionsX.contains($0.x)})
                middleRandomArrayLength1 =  UInt32(middleArray1.count)
                middleRandomPointIndex1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(middleRandomArrayLength1))
                spritesPath.append(middleArray1[middleRandomPointIndex1])

                middleIndex1 = leftPositions.indexOf(middleArray1[middleRandomPointIndex1])!
                middleArray1 = left[middleIndex1]
                let middleArray1X = middleArray1.map({ $0.x })
                var midArray2 = secondArray.filter({middleArray1X.contains($0.x)})

                midArray2 = midArray2.filter({element in point.x < element.x && topTest[nextArrayIndex].x > element.x })

                middleRandomArrayLength2 =  UInt32(midArray2.count)
                middleRandomPointIndex2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(middleRandomArrayLength2))
                spritesPath.append(midArray2[middleRandomPointIndex2])
            }

            else    {
                let secondArrayX = secondArray.map({ $0.x })
                middleArray1 = firstArray.filter({secondArrayX.contains($0.x)})
                middleArray1 = middleArray1.filter({element in point.x < element.x && topTest[nextArrayIndex].x > element.x })
                middleRandomArrayLength1 =  UInt32(middleArray1.count)
                middleRandomPointIndex1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(middleRandomArrayLength1))
                spritesPath.append(middleArray1[middleRandomPointIndex1])
             }
        }
    }
    }
```

The images below show that `secondArray` and `middleArray` contain similar elements and should not be empty

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should strip out all the irrelevant code before displaying the error and, preferably, make it so the sample code can be pasted into a playground and run.  That would make it much easier for others the see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can see an issue. The line that's crashing is:

`spritesPath.append(middleArray2[middleRandomPointIndex2])` right?

So my theory is that if middleArray2 is empty then the index returned by arc4random_uniform is zero. But the array doesn't have a zeroeth element.

If so, check for this condition before getting the array element. Might be a good time to factor the random index code out into its own function, you're using it quite a bit and it would simplify your design.

Maybe:

```
func randomElement(fromArray array:[T]) -> T? {
        let upperBound = UInt32(array.count)
        guard upperBound > 0 else { return nil }
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(upperBound))
        return array[index]
    }

    let a = randomElement(fromArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])    // 4
    let b = randomElement(fromArray: ["red", "green", "blue"]) // "red"
    let c = randomElement(fromArray: [Double]())               // nil
```

This function returns an optional because the array may not have any elements to return!

Comment: Yep, just checked this out: arc4random_uniform(0) does indeed return zero. Kind of an edge case on arc4random I guess.

Comment: Obviously, the same issue would apply to all the other array lookups.